# Out of domain development, C#/.net error: "The user name or password is incorrect."

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, cross-domain

I am developing on a machine that is not connected to the company's domain.

- I am connected to the company VPN
- When debugging/running the project from Visual Studio 2015, most things work fine. The error I'm running into is that on a remote server the app needs to create a folder. Though I can connect to this server by running remote desktop
- I have tried doing runas /netonly /user:domain\user "devenv.exe" for VS2015 with my domain credentials, but that does not seem to work
- I am running the app on a local IIS app pool

Connecting to SSMS works great using runas, but I can't get visual studio to work with it. I do not want to join the domain to resolve this issue, are there any options available?

Edit: I can access the server through windows explorer by providing the correct credentials, so I am most certainly able to access the server, but it seems the app pool account is not.

Comment: You say on a local IIS app pool, as in local to the remote server or local to your computer? 

You should be able to have the app authenticate into AD without having to join the domain also...

You may want to consider posting this in server fault also.

Comment: By local I mean local to my computer. I created a domain user account, added the user account to IIS_ISURS, and made that user the identity for the app pool (this matches the machine's setup that is connected to the domain).

Comment: Did you setup a user account in your pool settings or it is running under default iis identity?

Comment: @T.S. I setup the user account manually

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying. You have IIS app that needs to do something on the server. Your app runs on iis pool. Pool has identity. If that identity is not known by network, it wouldn't allow your app to perform certain operations. Go to pool properties and set some real identity

Comment: @T.S. Sorry I misunderstood. I did make a user account locally that matches my domain account name and added that to the IIS identity, Though I still get the error.

Comment: That is not going to work. You need domain identity

Comment: Just to be sure, the user account created should match the domain account name and the IIS identity should be in the format "domain\user"?

Comment: Look. you VPN into network - use that account. Or ask company to give you app special account so that your application can perform over the network tasks, like create a folder. Forget local user. Local user is user to your machine, AD has no idea about it